# PHP Oracle Connection undefined

Tags: php, oracle, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I can't access with oracle `oci_connect` in wamp. I modified `php.ini` and added oracle instantclient_12_1. The phpinfo file has oci enabled, but I ut can't access the `oci_connect` method. I am trying to access remote oracle server through oci_connect method.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: fatal error: call to undefined function oci_connect()

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Verify php.ini file inside php as well as apache folder they are fine for OCI configuration. Make sure they are not commented.
> 2. The oci*.dlls are also present in php/ext folder.
> 3. Also verify in wamp PHP extensions - php_oci8 is enabled.

Once all done `restart Wamp` and OCI should work fine.

Comment: Thank you CloudFreezer,

 Tried by changing apache php.ini and PHP php.ini,
 php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll already available on ext,
Wamp oci is enabled (showing on phpinfo() with authors)